# converting long to wide with columns starting at zero

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following data

```
county<-c(a,a,a,b,b,c)
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
data<-data.frame(county,id)
```

I need to convert from long to wide and get the following output

```
county<-c(a,b,c)
id__0<-c(1,4,6)
id__1<-c(2,5,##NA##)
id__2<-3,##NA##,##NA##)
data2<-data.frame(county,id__0,id__1,id__2)
```

My main problem is not in converting from long to wide, but how to make the columns start with id__0.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an intermediate variable by grouping according to `county` and using `mutate` to build a sequence from 0 upwards for each county, *then* `pivot_wider` on that:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  mutate(id_count = seq(n()) - 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(county, names_from =id_count, values_from = id, names_prefix = "id_")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   county [3]
#>   county  id_0  id_1  id_2
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a          1     2     3
#> 2 b          4     5    NA
#> 3 c          6    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>